# Hat Overlaps with Profile

Tags: discussion, bug, profile-page, winter-bash, gravatar

This is a minor bug with the new hats, but searching “hat overlap” in Math Meta brings up no questions, so this one might as well be the question for this issue. Here is a new hat which has a shape such that it sticks out when too big:

[image]

Notice how the Telescope overlaps the “member”, “profile”, and “activity” icons/text in the user profile. What can be done about this error? It probably can be fixed with hat size restrictions, but that would depend on whether the mobile version of (Math) Stack Exchange has the same error. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: There are controls to move, rotate, resize the hat. Just click on "show controls" box. You may check my profile icon where the hat is positioned properly.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks, but I do know how to reposition, it is just that it is possible to position the hat purposely in such a way that it a intersects with other objects.

Comment: There are controls to resize and rotate as well. Make the hat smaller and rotate if you wish.

Comment: This seems like a non-issue to me.  You can position the hat wherever you want.  If you don't want it to cover parts of the UI, then don't put it there.  Or, better yet, just turn off hats entirely.

Comment: It is ironic how this question was only closed one year after being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the hat here

[image]

Then you will get something like this

[image]

Now you can choose the position of the hat or change the hat.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to change the hat positioning. The point of the post is that there is a bug where the hat can overlap with unintended objects.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Hat itself can't decide where to place. You yourself have to resize and rechange image size and image position

Comment: I do not have a preference if the hats are out of position. Also, this matter may not be a problem for many, so I will accept.